# Embed readme file snippet into another one

Tags: github, documentation, embed, readme

Is it possible to embed a readme file snippet into another one?

E.g:

Let's assume that I have two different README files called **Readme1** and **Readme2**, where 
**Readme1** contains **Readme2** snippet. Right now I have copied the content of **Readme2** snippet into **Readme1** section.

This has the disadvantage that whenever I change **Readme2** snippet, I have to additionally change **Readme1** section.

Is there some kind of statement to embed one readme file snippet into another?

e.g.

```html
<embedSnippet src="./Readme2.md" startLine="5" endLine="15" />
```

Comment: Which documentation system do you use?

Comment: I use simple Readme.md files from github